# Print string and variable contents on the same line in R

Tags: r, printing

Is there a way to print text and variable contents on the same line? For example,

```
wd <- getwd()
print("Current working dir: ", wd)
```

I couldn't find anything about the syntax that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 381, accepted):

You can use `paste` with `print`

```
print(paste0("Current working dir: ", wd))
```

or `cat`

```
cat("Current working dir: ", wd)
```

Comment: You probably want `sep = ''` or you'll get an extra space.

Comment: Using `cat()` I get a `NULL` at the end :(

Comment: @ragesz i only get null on the end if you put the cat inside of a print like:
`print(cat("test", var))`  which should be `cat("test", var)`

Answer (score 76):

> {glue} offers much better string interpolation, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119797/946850). Also, as Dainis rightfully mentions, `sprintf()` is not without problems.

There's also `sprintf()`:

```
sprintf("Current working dir: %s", wd)
```

To print to the console output, use `cat()` or `message()`:

```
cat(sprintf("Current working dir: %s\n", wd))
message(sprintf("Current working dir: %s\n", wd))
```

Comment: Another nice option! This is very similar to other scripting languages and very convenient if you have a text where you want to implement multiple variables. Thanks!

Comment: by far the most convenient option, especially if you're composing a function argument. with paste it quickly becomes an unreadable mess.

Comment: Note that `sprintf` does not print, it just formats the string. Something like print(sprintf(...)) is necessary inside scripts.

Answer (score 28):

Or using `message`

```
message("Current working dir: ", wd)
```

@agstudy's answer is the more suitable here

Comment: Wow very straightforward!

Answer (score 21):

Easiest way to do this is to use `paste()`

```
> paste("Today is", date())
[1] "Today is Sat Feb 21 15:25:18 2015"
```

`paste0()` would result in the following:

```
> paste0("Today is", date())
[1] "Today isSat Feb 21 15:30:46 2015"
```

Notice there is no default seperator between the string and x. Using a space at the end of the string is a quick fix:

```
> paste0("Today is ", date())
[1] "Today is Sat Feb 21 15:32:17 2015"
```

Then combine either function with `print()`

```
> print(paste("This is", date()))
[1] "This is Sat Feb 21 15:34:23 2015"
```

Or

```
> print(paste0("This is ", date()))
[1] "This is Sat Feb 21 15:34:56 2015"
```

As other users have stated, you could also use `cat()`

Answer (score 15):

The [{glue} package](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) offers string interpolation. In the example, `{wd}` is substituted with the contents of the variable. Complex expressions are also supported.

```r
library(glue)

wd <- getwd()
glue("Current working dir: {wd}")
#> Current working dir: /tmp/RtmpteMv88/reprex46156826ee8c
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Note how the printed output doesn't contain the `[1]` artifacts and the `"` quotes, for which other answers use `cat()`.

Comment: I like this glue package because the format of printing numbers and strings in the same sentence is similar to python's syntax!

Answer (score 9):

As other users said, cat() is probably the best option.

@krlmlr suggested using sprintf() and it's currently the third ranked answer. sprintf() is not a good idea. From R documentation:

> The format string is passed down the OS's sprintf function, and incorrect formats can cause the latter to crash the R process.

There is no good reason to use sprintf() over cat or other options.

Answer (score 2):

you can use paste0 or cat method to combine string with variable values in R

For Example:

```
paste0("Value of A : ", a)

cat("Value of A : ", a)
```

Answer (score 1):

A trick would be to include your piece of code into `()` like this:

```
(wd <- getwd())
```

which means that the current working directory is assigned to `wd` and then printed.

Answer (score 0):

wd<- "D:/user"
print(paste0("Current working directory: ", wd))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).